# Highlight Mainmenu by the pageTheme

Tags: jquery, menu, highlight

I want to highlight the mainMenu when a submenu page is displayed.

```
<ul id="nav">
            <li class="topMenu"><a class="topMenuA"  href='@Url.Action("Index", "SavedViews")'>Saved Views</a></li>
            <li class="topMenu"><a class="topMenuA" > Administration</a> 
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "ServerLogs")>Server Logs</a></li> 
           </ul>  
       </li>
       <li class="topMenu"><a class="topMenuA"> Diagnostics </a>
            <ul class="subnav">
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "DiagOverview")>Diagnostics Overview</a></li> 
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("TableView", "DiagOverview")>Diagnostics Table View</a></li> 
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("ERData", "DiagOverview")>Event Recorder Data</a></li> 
            </ul>
           </li>          
</ul>
```

At the bottom of each page, I defined pageTheme, e.g:

```
<script>
    pageTheme = "Administration";
    pageName  = "Location";
</script>
```

I encounter errors with the following code for the highlighting purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav li.topMenu").removeClass("menuActive");
    $("#nav li.topMenu").filter(function (index) {
        return $(this).children('.topMenuA').text() === pageTheme;
    }).addClass("menuActive");
});
```

I guess the filtering part (trying to get the exact top menu li) is a problem. What did I do wrong? Any help / suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some hrefs are not delimited in this code.

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` doesn't trim whitespace so `$(this).children('.topMenuA').text()` doesn't equal `pageTheme` where pageTheme = `Administration` and the anchor looks like this

```
<a ...> Administration</a>
```

Use [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

```
return $.trim($(this).children('.topMenuA').text()) === pageTheme;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vnjnH/)

Comment: WOW Popnoodles,  You are wonderful.  That solves the problem.